# Why can't we construct a PRG from a one-way function and hc, but only one-way permutation

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function, hard-core-predicate

From Katz & Lindell's book, theorem 7.19:

> Let f be a one way permutation with hard-core predicate hc.
>
> Then the algorithm $G(s)=f(s)||hc(s)$ is a PRG with expansion factor $\ell(n)=n+1$.

But what about if we use a one-way function? I know that there could be $f(x)=f(x^{'})$ when $x\neq x^{'}$, we lost some entropy here, but what breaks the theorem actually?

Answer (score 4):

The proof of Theorem 7.19 explicitly uses that $f(r)$ for a uniformly random bitstring $r$ is distributed like $r$ when $f$ is a permutation*. I don't have the energy to reprint the proof here to show exactly how the distribution of $f(r)$ is used, but it should be clear that it can be useful to know this about $f(r)$ when arguing that $G$ is a PRG.

If you want a counterexample when $f$ is not a permutation you can see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52202/25923).

*This is the part of the proof that says

> using the fact that  $f$ is a permutation for the second equality

for those who have access to the book.